# How to find out what algorithm [ encryption ] are supported by my JVM?

Tags: java, encryption, jvm, jasypt

I am using Jasypt for encryption. This is my code:

```
public class Encryptor {    
    private final static StandardPBEStringEncryptor pbeEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    private final static String PASSWORD = "FBL";
    private final static String ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES";

    static{
        pbeEncryptor.setPassword( PASSWORD );
        //pbeEncryptor.setAlgorithm( ALGORITHM );       
    }

    public static String getEncryptedValue( String text ){
        return pbeEncryptor.encrypt( text );
    }

    public static String getDecryptedValue( String text ){
        return pbeEncryptor.decrypt( text );
    }

}
```

Uncomment the `setAlgorithm` line and it will throw an exception

> **org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException**:
>   Encryption raised an excep tion. A
>   possible cause is you are using strong
>   encryption algorithms and you have not
>   installed the Java Cryptography Ex
>   tension (JCE) Unlimited Strength
>   Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java
>   Virtual Machine

api says:

> Sets the algorithm to be used for
>   encryption Sets the algorithm to be
>   used for encryption, like
>   PBEWithMD5AndDES.
>
> This algorithm has to be supported by
>   your JCE provider (if you specify one,
>   or the default JVM provider if you
>   don't) and, if it is supported, you
>   can also specify mode and padding for
>   it, like ALGORITHM/MODE/PADDING.

refer: http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/apidocs/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html#setAlgorithm%28java.lang.String%29

Now, when you comment 'setAlgorithm' it will use the default Algorithm [ i guess it is md5 ], and it will work fine. That means md5 is supported by my JVM. Now, how to find out what other encryption algorithms are supported by my JVM.

Thanks,

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following will list all the providers and the algorithms supporter. What version of Java are you using? Unless you're on an old version JCE should be included as standard.

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;

public class SecurityListings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
            System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName());
            for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
                System.out.println("  Algorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit:
Any reason why you don't use the standard stuff from the javax.crypto package?

1) Generate a `Key` using

```
Key key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm).generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray()));
```

2) Create a `Cipher` using

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
```

3) Init your cipher with the key

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

4) Do the encrypting with

```
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data)
```

Comment: Instead of: System.out.println("  Algorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm()); use System.out.println(" " + service); and you'll be able to see the levels of encryption available. For example, the following indicates that 128 bit AES encryption is supported, but not 256 bit AES: SunJCE: Cipher.AES -> com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher
... SupportedModes=ECB|CBC|PCBC|CTR|CTS|CFB|OFB|CFB8|CFB16|CFB24|CFB32|CFB40|CFB48|CFB56|CFB64|OFB8|OFB16|OFB24|OFB32|OFB40|OFB48|OFB56|OFB64|CFB72|CFB80|CFB88|CFB96|CFB104|CFB112|CFB120|CFB128|OFB72|OFB80|OFB88|OFB96|OFB104|OFB112|OFB120|OFB128}

Comment: The code list a lot of algorithms that can't be used. Not so helpful code.

Answer (score 4):

The Jasypt command line tool now comes with a script for doing this called `listAlgorithms.bat` for windows and `listAlgorithms.sh` for Linux.

You can find instructions on how to download and use it here: http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html#Listing_algorithms

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have it installed already, then you need to install the JCE (Java Cryptography Extension) which provides support for the algorithms.

You can see how to install here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderInstalling

The library can be found here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code posted by @Qwerky, but it's not very helpful. I had added the latest BouncyCastle provider, and the results I got were very confusing. This shows in better detail who's the provider, version, and the algorithm type and name.

```
for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
    System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName() + " version: " + provider.getVersion());
    for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
        System.out.printf("  Type : %-30s  Algorithm: %-30s\n", service.getType(), service.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is still a 'pending' question asked by Qwerky: why using Jasypt instead of using javax.crypto?

Well, I would recommend using Jasypt as it is a simple way to crypto for beginners and highly configurable for experienced users.

With Jasypt, you can start taking benefit of javax.crypto quickly with a little knowledge of JCE and the cryptography. Whether you want to manage user passwords or encrypt/decrypt data, the framework provides a simple abstraction to the question.

In the same time, the framework exposes all the possibilities of the JCE specification to allow experienced users to be in full control.

In addition to this, Jasypt provides many more features out-of-the-box for well known questions (dealing with sensitive data stored in the database, ...)

Comment: If he want to ask a question he shouldnt put it in an answer. This is not a discussion thread

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 and above,

```
Stream.of(Security.getProviders()).flatMap(mapper -> Stream.of(mapper.getServices())).flatMap(Set::stream)
                .map(Provider.Service::getAlgorithm).distinct().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```