# Which versions of Android support which package signing algorithms?

Tags: android, sha

Given that I want to support all android devices which are, say, *Froyo* or later, what's the most secure signing algorithm I can use? I do not need to place my *APK* in *Android Market*.

I know, for instance, that some phones support `sha1withrsa` but not `sha256withrsa` ([Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38321)).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [android dev guide on signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp).
The current default method is `SHA1withRSA`:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

while a few years ago the signing method recommended was `MD5withRSA`.

---

> [...] what's the most secure signing algorithm I can use?

Are you concerned with some specific attack that makes you think that `SHA1withRSA` or `SHA256withRSA` would be more secure?  I can't foresee any scenario.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the current (Jan 2014) advice in the http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html doc. But I can attest that only MD5withRSA seems to work on the Sony Xperia E phone (Android 4.1) that I have in front of me.

Comment: They use `SHA1withRSA` as default/recommended method as of May 2015.