# SpongyCastle Provider loads SHA1withRSA algorithm, but still not available

Tags: android, maven, digital-signature, spongycastle

I am using [SpongCastle Provider](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle) v1.51. I added following maven to my project which are as follows(only relevant to SpongyCastle)

Based on answer [here from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710916/1225413), Already have added [SpongyCastle PGP](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/pg/1.51.0.0) to `maven pom` file.

I am still testing on debugging and not using any `Proguard` features, whatsoever.

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madgag.spongycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.51.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madgag.spongycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>prov</artifactId>
            <version>1.51.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madgag.spongycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>pg</artifactId>
            <version>1.51.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Following is the code for signing

```
private Document sign(Document document, boolean paramBoolean)throws Exception{
        if (System.getenv("SKIP_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE") != null) {
            return document;
        }

        X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate)this.ks.getCertificate(this.alias);
        Logger.d(TAG, "document base uri "+document.getBaseURI());
        if(!Init.isInitialized()){
            Logger.d(TAG, "initialzing the Init");
            Init.init();
        }else{
            Logger.d(TAG, "already initialzed");
        }
//      Logger.d(TAG, ""+localX509Certificate.get);
        XMLSignature localXMLSignature = new XMLSignature(document,"", XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);
        document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(localXMLSignature.getElement());
        Transforms localTransforms = new Transforms(document);
        localTransforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature");
        localXMLSignature.addDocument("", localTransforms, XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);
        X509Data localX509Data = new X509Data(document);
        localXMLSignature.getKeyInfo().add(localX509Data);
        localX509Data.addSubjectName(x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        localX509Data.addCertificate(x509Certificate);
        localXMLSignature.sign(this.privateKey);
        return document;
    }

    public String signXML(String paramString, boolean paramBoolean)
    {
/*      BouncyCastleProvider provider=new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Set<Service>service=provider.getServices();

        PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
         Iterator<Service> itr=service.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()){
             Service ser=itr.next();
             ser.
         }*/
        //added spongycastle provider here
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
//      new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider().
//      Security.addProvider(new );
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory localDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            localDocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            Document localDocument = sign(localDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(paramString))), paramBoolean);
            StringWriter localStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(localDocument), new StreamResult(localStringWriter));
            String str = localStringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
            return str;
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
            localException.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while digitally signing the XML document", localException);
        }
    }
```

The log stack trace

```
05-04 11:26:34.716: W/dalvikvm(10319): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity_en_US'
05-04 11:26:34.716: W/dalvikvm(10319): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity_en'
05-04 11:26:34.746: W/dalvikvm(10319): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity'
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319): org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: The requested algorithm SHA1withRSA does not exist. Original Message was: MessageDigest SHA1withRSA implementation not found
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.MessageDigestAlgorithm.getInstance(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.addDocument(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.addDocument(Unknown Source)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.helper.DigitalSigner.sign(DigitalSigner.java:78)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.helper.DigitalSigner.signXML(DigitalSigner.java:106)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.client.AuthClient.authenticate(AuthClient.java:50)
05-04 11:26:34.846: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.client.AuthRequest.authenticateRequest(AuthRequest.java:138)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.activity.MainActivity$AuthenticateResultAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:163)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.activity.MainActivity$AuthenticateResultAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-04 11:26:34.856: W/System.err(10319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while digitally signing the XML document
05-04 11:26:34.866: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.helper.DigitalSigner.signXML(DigitalSigner.java:115)
05-04 11:26:34.866: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.client.AuthClient.authenticate(AuthClient.java:50)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.auth.client.AuthRequest.authenticateRequest(AuthRequest.java:138)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.activity.MainActivity$AuthenticateResultAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:163)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at com.companyname.project.activity.MainActivity$AuthenticateResultAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-04 11:26:34.876: W/System.err(10319):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Q.1** Why is it `SHA1WithRSA` algorithm not available, Even after `SpongyCastle` loads the algorithm?

**Q.2** Why in the world Android does not support Class loading as it is java using `.class`, which is used by JAXB(I am trying to marshall/pack an XML and digitally sign it). It increase my development time from days into weeks.

```
Poor android does not support XML that good.
```

Please feel free to ask for further clarifications. Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**

I have added following code from here, to get list of Algorithms

```
Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
//      new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider().
//      Security.addProvider(new );

        for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
            System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName());
            for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
                System.out.println("  Algorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm());
            }
        }
```

**Output for list of Algorithms (Not Complete, Only Specific)**

```
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: DETECDSA
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: SEED-GMAC
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: RC5
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: CERTIFICATE
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: POLY1305-CAMELLIA
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: HC256
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: VMPC-KSA3
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: DESMAC64

05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA

05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: BouncyCastle
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: SKIPJACK
05-04 12:13:48.145: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: DESEDEMAC
05-04 12:13:48.155: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: POLY1305-CAMELLIA
05-04 12:13:48.155: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: SHA3-224
05-04 12:13:48.155: I/System.out(22193):   Algorithm: Skein-512-384
```

Algorithm is not available even after being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting the provider in a wrong way. To insert spongycastle as security provider in your app, you need to initialise it like this

```
    public class Sample {

    static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    public void printProviders() {
        for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
            System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName());
            for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
                System.out.println("  Algorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont know what the problem is, i winded up sending object attributes to server, where i marshall into XML and then sign it on java server end, where it works beautifully. P.s not using spongecastle there