# Trying to create a ECDH keypair in Java

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, ecdh

I am needing to migrate some simple KeyPair creation from Javascript to Java.  Using the NodeJS crypto package, this was extremely simple:

```
const keyPair = crypto.createECDH("prime256v1");
keyPair.generateKeys();
```

You can then use the generated keyPair to generate public and private keys to exchange data with our server.

I have found several code samples written in Java that generate ECDH Key Pairs using BouncyCastle, but they all throw the following exception:

java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPrivateKey

It would seem this should be as trivial as it was in Node.  What am I missing?

I tried the suggested code, and I'm getting the [similar] exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:896)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1399)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1330)
        at com.strivve.Encryption.encryptAES256(Encryption.java:42)
        at com.strivve.App.go(App.java:26)
        at com.strivve.App.main(App.java:14)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace indicates you are trying to use the EC key in `Cipher`. Java `Cipher` does not implement ECDH; Java `KeyAgreement` does. Generate the EC keypair, use it in `KeyAgreement` ECDH to produce a shared secret (this is the equivalent of nodejs crypto's `ecdh.computeSecret`), and use _that shared secret_ to create the key(s) used for symmetric encryption (and authentication, I hope) in `Cipher`

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 you're absolutely right.  The KeyAgreement does precisely that, and I was just missing that step.

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly easy as in NodeJs to generate an ECDH key pair, but you need to know the curve name used in Java. The curve "prime256v1" is known in Java with "secp256r1" and the SunEC crypto provider has an implementation for it.

This is a result of the program below (Java print outs the synonym curve names in detail):

```
Java generate an EC keypair
privateKey: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl@ffff97b7
publicKey: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 41232853336475799847910994406242230229392118856956796272263514934771986125833
  public y coord: 39545744123202785115112968739657610229201870815399428487100236626986481235670
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
```

full code without any exception handling:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        System.out.println("Java generate an EC keypair");
        String ecdhCurvenameString = "secp256r1";
        // standard curvennames
        // secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1]
        // secp384r1 [NIST P-384]
        // secp521r1 [NIST P-521]
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec(ecdhCurvenameString);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecParameterSpec);
        KeyPair ecdhKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("privateKey: " + privateKey);
        System.out.println("publicKey: " + publicKey);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Feb. 7th 2021**:
The code runs on Open Java 11 that has the SunEC provider included, that's why you don't see any additional library to import. Maybe your Java does not include the provider or it is disabled, kindly run my simple provider test - this is the result on Java 11:

```
Provider: SUN version: 11.0
Provider: SunRsaSign version: 11.0
Provider: SunEC version: 11.0
Provider: SunJSSE version: 11.0
Provider: SunJCE version: 11.0
Provider: SunJGSS version: 11.0
Provider: SunSASL version: 11.0
Provider: XMLDSig version: 11.0
Provider: SunPCSC version: 11.0
Provider: JdkLDAP version: 11.0
Provider: JdkSASL version: 11.0
Provider: SunPKCS11 version: 11.0
```

code:

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
 
public class A05_CryptoProvider {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683302/how-to-find-out-what-algorithm-encryption-are-supported-by-my-jvm/3683915#3683915
        for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
            System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName() + " version: " + provider.getVersion());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I originally tried (although I used bouncycastle as the provider. I am still getting the error in the original question. Do I need to install an additional package?

Comment: see my edited answer regarding security provider in Java

Comment: OP's stacktrace is failing in Cipher not KeyPairGenerator; this is not due to lack of provider, but rather no Cipher can use an EC key.

Comment: As I commented in the original question, @dave_thompson_085 is correct.